# Bitmap.compress compression ratio based on the parameters

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using the `Bitmap.compress` method is there any way to predetermine the size of the output file based on the parameters that are chosen?

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap.compress() includes the compression algorithm parameters.
If you need to change sizes for reducing memory allocation for your image, you exactly need to use scaling of your image using Bitmap.Options, computing bitmap bounds at first and then decoding it to your specified size.

like this :

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap preview_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
```

Comment: As far as I have seen in the Android docs if inSampleSize is set >1 it will return a smaller sized image [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) But is there any way to calculate what will be the size after this compression?